# sql case statement in where clause , need to join check on different tables on different cases

Tags: sql

```
SELECT     
    nc.status 
FROM
    newcustomer nc 
INNER JOIN 
    #salesexec UserFiltr ON UserFiltr.userid = nc.reportedby 
LEFT JOIN  
    distributor d ON nc.distributorid = d.distributorid 
LEFT JOIN  
    shop s ON S.shopid = Nc.shopid 
LEFT JOIN  
    shoptype st ON st.shoptypeid = s.shoptypeid 
LEFT JOIN  
    #orgshop Orgfiltr ON Orgfiltr.organizationid = D.organizationid 
WHERE      
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, nc.mobiletransactiondate, 101) BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
    AND 
      CASE nc.status 
         WHEN 1 
            THEN (st.shoptype IS NULL OR st.shoptype = '' OR st.shoptype <> 'DISTRIBUTOR') 
            ELSE (nc.shoptype IS NULL OR nc.shoptype = '' OR nc.shoptype <> 'DISTRIBUTOR') 
     END 
GROUP BY    
    reportedby
```

Comment: Tag the dbms. (And that group by seems to be invalid.)

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: You case sintax is wrong try explain in words what do need  for this case statement (when 1 THEN ......)

Comment: yes the syntax is wrong... i needed someone to correct it for me.. sorry i did'nt mention it in the description

Comment: If this is for **SQL Server**, then you must realize that `CASE` is an **expression** (like `a+b`) that returns a **single, atomic value** - not snippets of code to be executed .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may looking for this

```
AND 
  1 = CASE WHEN nc.status = 1 AND (st.shoptype IS NULL OR st.shoptype ='' OR st.shoptype <> 'DISTRIBUTOR' ) 
           THEN 1
           WHEN (nc.shoptype IS NULL OR  nc.shoptype ='' OR nc.shoptype<> 'DISTRIBUTOR' )
           THEN 1 
      END
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I can see what you're trying to do.

I would use something like this:

```
WHERE CASE nc.STATUS 
        WHEN 1 THEN st.shoptype
        ELSE nc.shoptype
      END IS NULL 
    OR
    CASE nc.STATUS 
        WHEN 1 THEN st.shoptype
        ELSE nc.shoptype
      END = ''
    OR
    CASE nc.STATUS 
        WHEN 1 THEN st.shoptype
        ELSE nc.shoptype
      END <> 'DISTRIBUTOR'
```

Answer (score 0):

You sintax for case is wrong could be that you wnat check

```
        ( st.shoptype IS NULL 
                  OR         st.shoptype ='' 
                  OR         st.shoptype<> 'DISTRIBUTOR' )
```

for assign a value eg:

```
       CASE nc.status 
                  WHEN (st.shoptype IS NULL 
                  OR         st.shoptype ='' 
                  OR         st.shoptype<> 'DISTRIBUTOR' )  THEN 1
                  WHEN  (nc.shoptype IS NULL 
                  OR         nc.shoptype ='' 
                  OR         nc.shoptype<> 'DISTRIBUTOR' )  THEN 2
                  ELSE 3
       END
```

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you need by you may try

```
       WHERE      
          CONVERT(VARCHAR, nc.mobiletransactiondate, 101) BETWEEN @FromDate  AND  @ToDate
        AND (
         (nc.status=1 and  (st.shoptype IS NULL 
                  OR         st.shoptype ='' 
                  OR         st.shoptype<> 'DISTRIBUTOR' )
          ) OR
            (nc.shoptype IS NULL 
                  OR         nc.shoptype ='' 
                  OR         nc.shoptype<> 'DISTRIBUTOR' ) 
       )
```